# NodeJS debugging in WebStorm

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I've got a `.js` file similar to

```js
import json from "$gameData/tags.json";

const func = () =>
    {
        // some function that uses the json variable
    }
```

While debugging `func`, at least WebStorm's debugger says that that `json` is undefined, even though it clearly is present (when read by console.log, or interacted with in any other way).

Binding it to another variable makes it debuggable, such as:

```
import jsonImport from "$gameData/tags.json";
json = jsonImport;
```

Why does it appear undefined to the debugger? I've searched all throughout the stack as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue when debugging ES6 modules transpiled by babel. Please see https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3957, https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/1468 for details. You will face the same problem when debugging with Chrome DevTools, for example.